# Issue in using google speech API with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-speech-api

I have used below code snippet for google speech to text recognition,

```
var speech = require('google-speech-api');
var opts = {
  file: 'speech.mp3',
  key: '<Google API Key>'
};
speech(opts, function (err, results) {
  console.log(results);
  // [{result: [{alternative: [{transcript: '...'}]}]}]
});
```

Then I tried to do

> "npm install google-speech-api"

from command prompt. It's giving error. 
Then, I did

> "npm install googleapis"

and it succeeded. 
I executed the Node.js script from command prompt "node myspeech.js"...it's throwing error as,

```
module.js:341
    throw err;


      ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'google-speech-api'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myspeechtest.js:1:76)
        at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

Comment: What is the error when you do `npm install google-speech-api`?

Comment: @DrakaSAN
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "google-speech-api"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Prasanta\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your error logs:

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! not found: git npm
ERR! npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

You need to have git installed on your system, and in your PATH.

For Windows, you can use [git-bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads), for Debian/Ubuntu, a simple `sudo apt-get install git` should do the tricks.

Comment: @DrakaSAN..Yes, it works now. But in the next step again I stuck. Made some changes in the script as below,
var request = require('superagent');
var speech = require('google-speech-api');
var opts = {
 filetype: 'flac',
 key: '<Google API key>'
};
request
  .get('./audio/0001.flac')
  .pipe(speech(opts, function (err, results) {
    if (err)
     console.log(err);
    else
     console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
  }));

Now when I execute the script from command prompt,
node myspeechtest.js
it doesn't give any output.

Comment: @PrasantaKChakravarty: You will need a new question for that, SO do not support moving goal questions. You should read [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
        const projectId = 'yourGoogleProjectId';
        let file="conf.json"//google exported this for you 
        var speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
            projectId: projectId,
            keyFilename: file
        });
        const fs = require('fs');
         const fileName = 'yourMp3FilePath';

       // Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
       const fileMp3 = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
       const audioBytes = fileMp3.toString('base64');
        const audio = {
            content:audioBytes
        };
        const config = {
            encoding: 'AMR_WB',
            sampleRateHertz: 16000,
            languageCode: 'en-US'
        };
        const request = {
            audio: audio,
            config: config
        };
        speech.recognize(request)
            .then((results) => {
                const transcription = results[0].results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
                console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('ERROR:', err);
            });
```